# How to make a pojo class for this type of json data, because in this category and subcategory are combine relation is only through a id

Tags: android

In this json my category and subcategory are combine, how can i arse and how to set in pojo class, i wan't to set in expandable list view, please help

```
 {
        "product_categories": [{
            "id": 24,
            "name": "Air Cooled",
            "slug": "air-cooled",
            "parent": 67,
            "description": "",
            "display": "subcategories",
            "image": "",
            "count": 4
        }, {
            "id": 33,
            "name": "Belt Driven",
            "slug": "bet-driven",
            "parent": 25,
            "description": "",
            "display": "default",
            "image": "",
            "count": 15
        }, {
            "id": 25,
            "name": "CNC LATHE SPINDLE",
            "slug": "cnclathespindle",
            "parent": 0,
            "description": "",
            "display": "default",
            "image": "",
            "count": 15
        }, {
            "id": 28,
            "name": "CNC MILLING SPINDLE",
            "slug": "cncmillingspindle",
            "parent": 0,
            "description": "",
            "display": "default",
            "image": "",
            "count": 9
        }, {
            "id": 29,
            "name": "Motorised",
            "slug": "singles",
            "parent": 25,
            "description": "",
            "display": "default",
            "image": "",
            "count": 0
        }, {
            "id": 21,
            "name": "MOTORIZED SPINDLE",
            "slug": "motorizedspindle",
            "parent": 0,
            "description": "",
            "display": "default",
            "image": "",
            "count": 11
        }, {
            "id": 30,
            "name": "Water Cooled",
            "slug": "water-cooled",
            "parent": 67,
            "description": "",
            "display": "subcategories",
            "image": "",
            "count": 7
        }, {
            "id": 67,
            "name": "Wood Acrylic Engraving",
            "slug": "wood-acrylic-engraving",
            "parent": 21,
            "description": "",
            "display": "products",
            "image": "",
            "count": 0
        }]
    }
```

In this json my category and subcategory are combine, how can i arse and how to set in pojo class, i wan't to set in expandable list view, please help

Comment: check this http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the json response and store the different categories in different arraylist and based on the user selection of your render position you can use the selected arraylist.

You can do this by parsing the json response like this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); // response is the json string that you are gettting from server

    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("product_categories");

    ArrayList<Categorydisplay> catDisList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Defaultdisplay> defaultDisList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        SomeModel someModel = new SomeModel();
        if (jsonObject.has("id")) {
            someModel.setId(jsonObject.getString("id"));
        }
        if (jsonObject.has("name")) {
            someModel.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
        }

        so on.....

        if(someModel.getDisplay().equals("default")){
            defaultDisList.add(someModel);
        }else{
            catDisList.add(someModel);
        }

    }
```